# R: summarise a dataframe with NAN in columns

Tags: r, summarize

I have the following data set:

```
  Data1      Data2      Data3
      3        NAN        NAN
      2        NAN        NAN
      3        NAN        NAN
    NAN          3        NAN
    NAN          5        NAN
    NAN          3        NAN
    NAN        NAN          7
    NAN        NAN          5
    NAN        NAN          1
```

I'd like to summarise it into this:

```
  Data1   Data2      Data3
      3       3          7
      2       5          5
      3       3          1
```

I've trying creating a row number, grouping by row number and applying `summarise`, but it's just filling the NaNs with 0.

```
data = data %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(row) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(across(c("Data1","Data2","Data3"), ~sum(., na.rm=T))) %>% 
  distinct(.)
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible example of your input data.

Comment: The dataset above is a fragment of my input data.

Comment: Please add data using `dput`. Do you have `NAN` as text or the value in R which is `NaN`. Adding data with `dput` will clarify that the way data is shown is not clear.

Comment: @MustardRecord The dataset above is not directly *reproducible*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have same number of `NaN`'s in each column as shown in the example you can use `na.omit` to drop those values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% summarise(across(.fns = na.omit))
#If in your data values are string 'NAN' then use the below
#df %>% summarise(across(.fns = ~.x[.x!= 'NAN']))

#  Data1 Data2 Data3
#1     3     3     7
#2     2     5     5
#3     3     3     1
```

In base R -

```
as.data.frame(sapply(df, na.omit))
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(Data1 = c(3, 2, 3, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN
), Data2 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, 3, 5, 3, NaN, NaN, NaN), Data3 = c(NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 7, 5, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In my data, the NaN weren't strings, so they were actually "not a number". Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compute the `sum`s then this will do:

```
data %>% 
  summarise(across(c("Data1","Data2","Data3"), ~sum(., na.rm=T)))
```

**EDIT**:

You can ge rid of the `NaN`values by using a combination of `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`:

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Data'), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(name) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest()
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Data1 Data2 Data3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     3     7
2     2     5     5
3     1     3     1
```

Or even more nicely:

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(df, na.omit)
```

Comment: I've tried that but it only replaces the NANs by 0

Comment: But isn't that acceptable? NaN stands for: not a number.

Comment: The structure I'm looking for is to squeeze the dataset, getting away all the cells with NaN and keeping only the cells with data. Each column has the same number of cells with data and cells with NAN, so the sizes should match between columns

Comment: I've edited the solution. Does it work now?

Comment: I've already implemented the other solution above, but thanks a lot!